# What is the first line of a function officially called?

Tags: function, definition

In programming, what is the official name of the first line of a function, where the line contains the function name and the parameters?

Here is an example of a function:

```
function example1(parameter1, parameter2)
{
    alert("example");
}
```

Is the first line called a function declaration? I am referring to the line:

```
function example1(parameter1, parameter2)
```

I am needing the official name. I have done some research, yet cannot find the answer. Is there some documentation that can help me out, and if so, where can I find this documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: Terminology varies between languages. There is no single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often called the method signature, although in your definition, the declaration of the method signature would normally include type information which would allow you to distinguish between different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

From what I learnt in class, I usually call it as *subroutine*, *procedure*, or *method* instead of *function*.

You might refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) to find out more.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  They're looking for the name of the line of syntax or grammar that defines a function, method, or procedure as a discrete unit of code.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with @mr-moose that this could be called a method signature, thought that term is usually used in strongly typed languages.  It looks like your code is JavaScript, so looking at the [ECMAScript 5 Specification](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php), I see the term *Function Declaration* used pretty regularly.  The standard can be a bit difficult to read, but I was unable to find anything more specific.

It really depends who you are talking to, or to what language you are referring.  Each community has it's own glossary of standard terms and different naming conventions.